# extract valid email address using regular expression and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I created a code to extract emails from websites:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = ""
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

content = soup.get_text()
emails_match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', content)
```

it works fine, but sometimes return emails with other text inside it from other element.
For example, if we try the code on this website: https://alliedsinterings.com/
it will returns phone number plus email:

```
print(email_match)
['743-2538info@alliedsinterings.com']
```

I want to get only the email address (without any text from other html elements)

when I try another regex, it returns the same, for example:

```
r'([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+){0,}'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract all emails from string with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769788/extract-all-emails-from-string-with-regex)

Comment: no, it doesn't answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.strings` instead of `.text`

```
import re

email = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+){0,}')

[x for x in soup.strings if email.search(x).group()]
```

---

```
['info@alliedsinterings.com']
```